# VBA: No CellTypeBlanks available

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a spreadsheet I'm working on where sometimes my `wRange` has no blank cells left to use.  In this case I want to jump to the end of the macro.  I'm currently using this:

```
On Error Resume Next
    wRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) = "0"
On Error GoTo -1
```

to deal with the error I get if there are no blank cells left after my other changes.

I'm planning on using a flag like

```
If wRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) is Blank Then
    Boolean emptycells = FALSE
End If
```

Is there a better way to go about doing this?  And if not, how do I go about coding this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
Dim blanks As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set blanks = wRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0

If blanks Is Nothing Then
    emptyCells = False
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

mielk's answer is perfectly fine, but from reading your question it sounds like the only reason you are even using the emptyCells boolean is to go to the end of macro. So I would not even bother with it and would instead modify mielk's answer in the following way:

```
Whateveryoursubsnameis()

    Dim rngBlanks As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngBlanks = wRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If blanks Is Nothing Then
        GoTo MacroEnd
    End If

    (rest of your macro's code)

MacroEnd:
End Sub
```